# Why can't the console define id?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, console

I'm trying to get the console to show the id as well as the latitude and longitude this is to ideally save it in an array which i can then store onto a mysql database. This involves the use of the google maps Javascript API.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
 var markers;
        function initMap() {    
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
            // this connects to the database
             function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {       
          downloadUrl('maps.php', function(data) {
      //        var cdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var lat = markerElem.getAttribute('lat');
              var lng = markerElem.getAttribute('lng');
              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {     
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); 
            lat = (results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            lng = (results[0].geometry.location.lng());
              var points = {};
              points.id = id.id;
              points.lat = map.getCenter().lat();
              points.lng = map.getCenter().lng();
              getlatlng(points);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
                             marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
        })   

            });   
          });
           function getlatlng(points) {
               console.log(points);
           }
             }
geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);

      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);

      }
        }

      function doNothing() {}

    </script>
```

When the console is loaded, the `id` will show up as undefined while the `lat` and `lng` will be displayed. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Why does the property `id` of your `markerElem` have a property `id`?

Comment: `points.id = id.id;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');` does not return an array, and here `points.id = id.id;` you attack the property 'id'. Changing it to `points.id = id;` should do the trick.